# shell_exec returns NULL but when tried from console, it works

Tags: linux, daemon, php

I have three php scripts. One, I start with init script. The second is started by the first one itself and the second then uses `shell_exec` to get output from the third script by passing various params to it periodically.

But it's not happening. When I `var_dump` the output of `shell_exec`, in the second script, I get `NULL`. But when I print the actual command which is used in `shell_exec` in the second script and try entering it into console, it works very well!

I tried the command from console of same user with which I start the init script.

This might be a permission issue. But I have the proper permissions setup i.e.

1. +x for the third script
2. the third script (actually all the three are) is owned by the same user and group I use the console with

Note - I tried starting the third script with shebang as well as by removing the shebang and adding `php` before the script path. With root everything runs fine.

Also, just another note, the first script redirects output of the second script to a log file (this is where I found the third script returning `NULL` on `shell_exec`)

UPDATE: The code from second script which uses `shell_exec`

```
$command = "/var/data/user-data.php '{$user}' '{$request['token']}' '{$request['secret']}'";
$data = json_decode( shell_exec( $command ), true );
```

I tried printing `$command` and also `var_dump( shell_exec( $command ) )`. The former one returns what is expected (the params) and the latter returns NULL

Comment: post the exact code your using

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Without directly commenting on what the problem is -

Stop. Don't shell out. This is a security minefield.

```
$command = "/var/data/user-data.php '{$user}' '{$request['token']}' '{$request['secret']}'";
```

What happens if the user passes, say:

```
http://yoursite.com/index.php?token=';rm -rf / #
```

Answer: Your entire server is erased (or at least anything the PHP script user can touch). Naturally there are other, more insidious things people can do. And this sort of vulnerability *can* and *will* be found by automated scanners, which will in turn automatically root your server.

So don't shell out, particularly when you're just calling another PHP script. Put your code into a function, include the php file containing it, and call the function when you need the data.

Comment: These files are not in web root and it's really just `$request` and not `$_REQUEST` :) But yeah, I liked the idea of including a script.

Comment: @KPL, doesn't matter if they're in the web root or not, if the user can control ANY of those variables, you're screwed. Even if you've got the security right (which is HIGHLY unlikely if you're even THINKING about shelling out for this), shelling out is slow and is actually more work than just putting the damn thing into a function.

Comment: this should be a comment, it's definitely not worthy of being an answer. The question and reason I am here is to find out why shell_exec is returning null. you didn't answer that. wtf is with the internet, everybody thinks that there's a better way of doing something. stfu and answer the question that was asked people.

Comment: @JonathonByrd, I refuse to give people advice that, if implemented, could make the internet a more dangerous place. There are generally better ways to do what you want than shelling out,  and in the specific case of the OP, almost certainly so. I would've made it a comment though, if there weren't size limits :) If you have a legit use case feel free to open another question - just be sure to cite this one so people don't think it's a duplicate.